# attributeError for @classmethod generated when python script is imported into another script but not when tested stand alone

Tags: python

I am trying to re-use some code from the CoderBot project to build my own web controlled robot.
I am using python3 on a raspberry PI and I have simplified the code just to generate the error.
'''
class myclass():
objClass = None
def **init**(self):
print("initialised")

```
    @classmethod
    def get_it(cls):
        if not cls.objClass:
            print("objClass does not exist")
            cls.objClass = myclass()
            print("created")
        return cls.objClass

def main(args):
    method_list = [method for method in dir(myclass) if method.startswith('_') is False]
    print(method_list)
    makeone = myclass.get_it()
    print(makeone)
    print(myclass.get_it())
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

'''

when I run this the following output is produced
'''

```
 ['get_it', 'objClass']
 objClass does not exist
 initialised
 created
 <__main__.myclass object at 0x7fbe6e1fa0>
 <__main__.myclass object at 0x7fbe6e1fa0>
```

'''

Everything is as I expected.

When I run this code in a  separate script
'''
import ct

```
def main(args):
    method_list = [attribute for attribute in dir(ct.myclass) if 
     callable(getattr(ct.myclass, attribute)) and attribute.startswith('__') is 
    False]
    print(method_list)
    two = ct.get_it()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

'''

The following output is produced:
'''
['get_it']

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/classTest/mainct.py", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/pi/classTest/mainct.py", line 30, in main
    two = ct.get_it()
 AttributeError: module 'ct' has no attribute 'get_it'
```

'''

This output is telling me that 'get_it' exists in the class, but not when I try and create one.
I am very confused and have looked at lots of tutorials but can't spot what I am doing wrong.
It is probably one of those errors where if I sat down and spoke to someone it would be obvious, but I can't spot it!

Steve

PS I hope the formatting is ok,

As jasonharper said, I was not referencing the class!
When I went back and looked at the original code I had not spotted the change in case.
so with my example the class MyClass should have been defined in a file myclass.py and then referenced as

from myclass import MyClass

then in the code
two = MyClass.get_it()

I have hopefully sorted out the formatting, the post was originally created on my PI and I spent 40 minutes trying to format it correctly.

This problem is definitely closed, thanks for replies

Comment: `ct` is a module, not a class.  Perhaps you want `ct.myclass.get_it()`.

Comment: Could you make sure your code is formatted correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Is "ct" your class?

two = ct()
two.get_it()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I think that is it, I will try it later on. I have been looking at it for ages.